# Result of .from_unixtime() pyspark function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I create spark dataframe and want to aggregate over 10 minutes interval from `timestamp` in unix format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=[
        'eventType',
        'detectedDuplicate',
        'detectedCorruption',
        'timestamp',
        'sessionId',
        'item_price',
        'partyId'
    ],
    index=range(5)
)
df['item_price'] = [4876, 13707, 3307, 3294, 3532]
df['timestamp'] = [
    1545127200000,
    1545127240589,
    1545127282370,
    1545127289430,
    1545127324726
]
```

Then I apply `.from_unixtime` function:

```
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Milliseconds")
out_df = tmp_df.withColumn('tmstmp', F.from_unixtime("timestamp"))
out_df[['timestamp', 'tmstmp']].toPandas()
```

But see strange result:

[image]

so my window function doesn't work also:

```
out_df.groupBy(F.window("tmstmp", "10 minutes")).agg(
                        F.sum(F.col("item_price")).alias("revenue")
                        ).show()
```

[image]

Comment: `out_df = sdf.withColumn('tmstmp', F.from_unixtime(F.col("timestamp")/1000))`